# Asynchronous sending emails for sales order in magneto2

Tags: magento2, sales

I want to sent sales order email at 2 mins of interval. If i enable Asynchronous sending means mail is not triggered. Whether we need to configure any cron job for this process if yes means please tell me the steps.